# getCssJsHtml function called twice on catalog page?

Tags: catalog, magento-1.6

On Magento CE1.6, on the catalog page access (both list and grid), log are generated in system.log :

```
Notice: Undefined index: items  in .../app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 167
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in .../app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 167
```

The function involved here is getCssJsHtml() called in the head.phtml file.

I've put some debug and find head.phtml is called twice, first time with good parameters, all design is loaded as expected, but the second time, without any parameters ($data['items'] is not defined).

I can't find where head.phtml is called the second time and it seems the problem occurs in all of my custom theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `head.phtml` template is assigned inside of the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` class. So grep your theme for `page/html_head` to find all instances of this block.

Comment: Thank you Tim ! It was that. I've installed a module for the catalog page (infinite scroll) and it seems this module is coded with feet. It calls a second time the head.phtml ... Solved, thank you again !